# how to append numbers to the end of array

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the dataset:

```
PCMW[i] = mol_wt(PC[i])
PCMW_Res = 800.0
PCMW_Asp = 1000.0

print(type(PCMW))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(PCMW)
[  69.60427822   86.65452228   96.0158615   105.97424623  116.56355183
  127.82144607  139.78983173  152.51537313  176.76697241  216.37941021
  262.9658499   318.21304727  384.50522493  465.34801801  566.16876358
  695.97421882  871.25289533 1663.70894284]

print(type(PCMW_Res))
<type 'float'>

print(PCMW_Res)
800.0

print(type(PCMW_Asp))
<type 'float'>

print(PCMW_Asp)
1000.0
```

Try this:

```
PCMW = np.append(PCMW, PCMW_Res, PCMW_Asp)
```

The error:

```
*TypeError:* 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

What is the proper way to append **PCMW_Res** and **PCMW_Asp** to the end of **PCMW**? I want the final dataset **PCMW** looks like this:

```
[  69.60427822   86.65452228   96.0158615   105.97424623  116.56355183
  127.82144607  139.78983173  152.51537313  176.76697241  216.37941021
  262.9658499   318.21304727  384.50522493  465.34801801  566.16876358
  695.97421882  871.25289533 1663.70894284  800.0        1000.0]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read the `np.append` docs.  Your third argument is wrong.

Comment: `np.append` docs: Signature: `np.append(arr, values, axis=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with np.hstack, you could do it as:

```
PCMW = np.hstack([PCMW, PCMW_Res, PCMW_Asp])
```

Output:

```
array([  69.60427822,   86.65452228,   96.0158615 ,  105.97424623,
        116.56355183,  127.82144607,  139.78983173,  152.51537313,
        176.76697241,  216.37941021,  262.9658499 ,  318.21304727,
        384.50522493,  465.34801801,  566.16876358,  695.97421882,
        871.25289533, 1663.70894284,  800.        , 1000.        ])
```